# Query for words with special characters and normal input in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, soundex

I have a database with special characters like `ā` or `ă` so when the input is something like `amor` I want to query also the word `āmor` or `ămor`. I used the `Sounds Like` function but it does not work properly.

Here is my question: How do I do that?

Comment: That's too bad. Did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to list problems.

Comment: @MarcB how is my edit? Did I polish the T well enough :p

Comment: if you use unicode charsets, then that kind of comparison is automatic. `select 'āmor' = 'amor'` -> `1`.